# Reading specific items from an XML

Tags: c#, xml

Let's start with my goal. I need to read through a rather large XML file, and extract 6 values. These values are located in lines in subgroup that I don't know how to access.

---

Here is the XML structure:

```
<Project Guid="9e9a67f8" Name="GameThings" Version="1.7">
  <Subsystems>
    <Values Name="Thing1">
      <Values Name="Stuff1" Type="int" Value="0" />
      <Values Name="Stuff2" Type="int" Value="5" />
    </Values>
    <Values Name="Thing2">
      <Values Name="Top" Type="int" Value="10" />
      <Values Name="Bottom" Type="int" Value="15" />
    </Values>
  </Subsystems>
  <OtherSystems>
    <Values Name="Thing3">
      <Values Name="Stuff3" Type="int" Value="0" />
      <Values Name="Stuff4" Type="int" Value="5" />
    </Values>
  </OtherSystems>
</Project>
```

What I'm trying to do here is retrieve the values from Project-Subsystems-Thing2. That's all I need. How do I do it?

---

Here is one of the things I tried:

```
        using (XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(Path + "Project.xml"))
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if(reader.)
            }
        }
```

But it basically stopped there. Here is another thing, that I made no sense of, it was mostly copy and past and my gut:

```
        XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
        xml.LoadXml(Path + "Project.xml");
        XmlNodeList nodes = xml.SelectNodes("/Project[@*]/Subsystems");
        foreach(XmlNode node in nodes)
        {
            if(node["Name"].Value == "GameInfo")
            {
                foreach(XmlNode stuff in node["Name"])
                {

                }
            }
        }
```

Same thing there.

Comment: A bunch of xpath examples: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: `I need to read through a rather large XML file, and extract 6 values.` + `What I'm trying to do here is retrieve the values from Project-Subsystems-Thing2.` "Thing2" only has 2 subnodes. Which `6` values do you need to retrieve, and where from exactly?

Comment: @dxiv the structure I provided is just an example. The real XML is much larger and contains a lot more "Thing" elements.

Comment: @GrantWinney Yes, they should, I was just quickly typing the example. Thanks, I'll edit.

Comment: Check my answer and tell me if help you.

Comment: user xml serializaiton and deserializarion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next time atleast post valid xml. You are taking all values nodes where the attribute name is Thing and after that taking the child nodes value from this element.

```
    private static void XDocumentLINQ()
        {
            string xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
<Project Guid=""9e9a67f8"" Name=""GameThings"" Version=""1.7"">
  <Subsystems>
    <Values Name=""Thing1"">
      <Values Name=""Stuff1"" Type=""int"" Value=""0"" />
      <Values Name=""Stuff2"" Type=""int"" Value=""5"" />
    </Values>
    <Values Name=""Thing2"">
      <Values Name=""Top"" Type=""int"" Value=""10"" />
      <Values Name=""Bottom"" Type=""int"" Value=""15"" />
    </Values>
  </Subsystems>
  <OtherSystems>
    <Values Name=""Thing3"">
      <Values Name=""Stuff3"" Type=""int"" Value=""0"" />
      <Values Name=""Stuff4"" Type=""int"" Value=""5"" />
    </Values>
  </OtherSystems>
</Project>";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

            var elements = doc.Descendants("Project").Elements("Subsystems").Elements("Values").Where(x=>x.Attribute("Name").Value == "Thing2").Elements("Values");

            foreach (XElement elem in elements)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(elem.Attribute("Name").Value + " value is: " + elem.Attribute("Value").Value);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();

        }
```

Comment: It isn't working, the list.Count is 0, and all of the names are exactly correct.

Comment: If you put in Console application you will see that it is working.

Comment: I wasn't using Linq before this, so what's the alternative to parsing text for XDocument? I am currently doing Load(path), and I suspect that's why it's not working.

Comment: If you are loading form correct path the Xdocument should be filled again. I don't know where is the problem, this code is working you need reference of System.Xml.Linq;

Comment: Figured it out. The problem was the elements are labeled "Value", not "Values"

Comment: how about xml serialization & deserialization?

Answer (score 1):

Use XML Serialization & Deserialization, that makes thing lot easier

**Class File For the XML**

```
  /// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class Project
{

    private ProjectValues[] subsystemsField;

    private ProjectOtherSystems otherSystemsField;

    private string guidField;

    private string nameField;

    private decimal versionField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("Values", IsNullable = false)]
    public ProjectValues[] Subsystems
    {
        get
        {
            return this.subsystemsField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.subsystemsField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public ProjectOtherSystems OtherSystems
    {
        get
        {
            return this.otherSystemsField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.otherSystemsField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string Guid
    {
        get
        {
            return this.guidField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.guidField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return this.nameField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.nameField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public decimal Version
    {
        get
        {
            return this.versionField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.versionField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class ProjectValues
{

    private ProjectValuesValues[] valuesField;

    private string nameField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Values")]
    public ProjectValuesValues[] Values
    {
        get
        {
            return this.valuesField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.valuesField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return this.nameField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.nameField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class ProjectValuesValues
{

    private string nameField;

    private string typeField;

    private byte valueField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return this.nameField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.nameField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string Type
    {
        get
        {
            return this.typeField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.typeField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public byte Value
    {
        get
        {
            return this.valueField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.valueField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class ProjectOtherSystems
{

    private ProjectOtherSystemsValues valuesField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public ProjectOtherSystemsValues Values
    {
        get
        {
            return this.valuesField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.valuesField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class ProjectOtherSystemsValues
{

    private ProjectOtherSystemsValuesValues[] valuesField;

    private string nameField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Values")]
    public ProjectOtherSystemsValuesValues[] Values
    {
        get
        {
            return this.valuesField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.valuesField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return this.nameField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.nameField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class ProjectOtherSystemsValuesValues
{

    private string nameField;

    private string typeField;

    private byte valueField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return this.nameField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.nameField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string Type
    {
        get
        {
            return this.typeField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.typeField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public byte Value
    {
        get
        {
            return this.valueField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.valueField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

**Code:**

```
XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Project));
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(xml);
        object obj = deserializer.Deserialize(reader);
        Project XmlData = (Project)obj;
        reader.Close();
        var val = XmlData.Subsystems.ToList().Where(x=>x.Values.ToList().Select(y=>y.Name).Contains("Thing2")).ToList();
```

Comment: A good way if you need to read much different info from the XML, but if you need to take just a couple of nodes from a complicated XML, then it is faster just to use XmlDocument or XDocument